How can i draw a custom shape like a top left corner as shown in below image in flutter

I want to create custom item widget like as image. I almost completed the widget but only top left green shape with price is remaining.
Can anyone out here help me out for the same. I want help for creating top left Green Shape.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html - the docs say: "Displays a diagonal message above the corner of another widget."

You can do it with Banner widget of flutter. Here's an example how to achieve this:
ClipRect(
  child: Banner(
    message: '\₹ 22',
    location: BannerLocation.topStart,
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Container(),//Your Custom Widget
  ),
)

Hope this helps you.

Already achieved through it. Looking for other options

So now another way you can use super_banners and ribbon_widget packages to achieve this.

I am seeking custom widget my dear

For custom widget you can use CustomClipper.

I know dear but at that i was in a hurry so i was looking for readymade code for it

I hope you get it now.
